# Encrypting file from source AEAD

Tags: performance, c, file, cryptography, encryption

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt file using source code directly. The issue is how to properly do it after reading the file.

```
int crypto_aead_encrypt(
    unsigned char *c, unsigned long long *clen,
    const unsigned char *m, unsigned long long mlen,
    const unsigned char *ad, unsigned long long adlen,
    const unsigned char *nsec,
    const unsigned char *npub,
    const unsigned char *k
)
```

Working code: (plaintext is char *)

```
for (start = 0; start < fileLength; start += 32)
    {
        int end = (start + 32);
        end = end > fileLength ? fileLength : end;

        strncpy(msg, plaintext + start, end - start);

        // encrypt
        crypto_aead_encrypt(ct, &clen, msg, mlen, ad, adlen, NULL, nonce, key);

        // decryption

        crypto_aead_decrypt(msg2, &mlen2, NULL, ct, clen, ad, adlen, nonce, key);
}
```

This is the function, and the max limit of the message `m` is 32 bits, which would make encrypting/decrypt very long for large files (ex. 1GB). Is there a way to perform the encrypting as fast as if it were from the library. Neglecting the code above, ex. how does OpenSSL do it when -in is provided?

The way I have it is to read the file, save it to an `char *` and then take 32 bits and enc each one. So I am wondering if there is a proper more correct way to do it.

Edit: reference implementation like [ascon](https://github.com/ascon/ascon-c/tree/caf2a13b7f4f6487ebb1949df2f70fb098da54a4/crypto_aead/ascon128v12/ref) or [photon-beetle](https://www.isical.ac.in/~lightweight/beetle/resource.html)

Comment: **Why** do you first read the entire file, and more importantly, **why** do you only encrypt 32 bits / 4 bytes at a time? That don't make no sense at all.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes 32 bits cause that's the max the algorithm accepts (max msg size for encrypting/decrypting blocks). And I'm not sure how else to do it without reading the entire file first, I read it and store it then process the stored

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused here. The GCM algorithm has a 96 bit nonce, and fills the rest of the 128 bit block size with a 32 bit counter. So you have 2^32 full blocks at your disposal, or about 64 GiB. That's - uh - slightly more than 32 bits (well, OK, the counter starts at 2, so you'd have 48 bytes less than that, better keep it at 32 GiB or 48 GiB).

Comment: Thanks! how do you suggest to do it then? I mean encrytping the plaintext directlt? I tried that but I kept getting error due to exceeding the limit. For example I am using [photon-beetle](https://www.isical.ac.in/~lightweight/beetle/resource.html) and particularly [this](https://github.com/ascon/ascon-c/blob/caf2a13b7f4f6487ebb1949df2f70fb098da54a4/tests/genkat_aead.c) as a tempalte to do the enc/dec where the max is 32

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what goes wrong; I'd have to debug the code for that. I can see in the photon code that `size_t Dlen_inblocks = (Dlen_inbytes + RATE_INBYTES - 1) / RATE_INBYTES;` which splits up the input as 4 byte blocks. That's not something you do if the total input can be 32 bits (which makes no sense whatsoever for an AEAD cipher).

Comment: Ah ok, and the other thing that the crypto_aead_encrypt takes in m as a unsigned char so that means after it passes there it's converted to uint8_t (`const uint8_t *Data_in`). In any case, I even tried again sending fill plaintext and the fill length but it's a buffer overflow due to the full plaintext I'm pretty sure 


**Edit:** I changed the code and was able to get it to work! however, not for large files (ex. 16mb), a stack overflow. I'm currently really stuck on where or how I could fix it though, tried different ways to debug it but no success so far

Comment: I guess the error shows the place where these kind of questions are more on topic :) Glad you got the initial issue solved. What I wrote was for GCM (which I wrongly assumed was the block cipher), if there is a block of 4 bytes then of course the algorithm may have different limits. You can e.g. split up the file in chunks and encrypt them separately. You'd have to create a MAC over the authentication tags though, otherwise the chunks may be reordere.d by an adversary.

Answer (score 2):

> So I am wondering if there is a proper more correct way to do it.

**binary data**

An encryption of a file should not assume it is text lacking a `'\0'`.  As a binary file, data may include *null characters* which will incorrectly copy using `strncpy()`.

```
// strncpy(msg, plaintext + start, end - start);
memcpy(msg, plaintext + start, end - start);
```

**LARGE files**

"for large files (ex. 1GB)" --> 1GB is not so large.  Rather than limit file size to the `int` range, use `size_t`.  That is typicality at least 2x the positive range or perhaps billions x.  Code is limited in design to `size_t` given the usage of a single array.   Might as well use as much range as possible.

```
size_t start;
... 
// int end = (start + 32);
size_t end = (start + 32);
```

Better code would use `unsigned long long` like the `int crypto_aead_decrypt(unsigned char* m, unsigned long long* mlen, ...)` signature.

Comment: Good point about the `int`. It made no sense for 32 bit input, but for larger input e.g. a 2 GiB - 1 max size may be prohibitive. The `strncpy` is interesting as well; I presumed readable text when I saw that, but that might be a somewhat presumptuous :)